# How to chain two VPNs? (basically tunneling through another tunnel)

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, vpn, proxy

Due to internet restrictions in my home country (Iran) which blocks all VPN traffic detected by DPI I can only connect to the internet using shared Obfuscated proxies (V2Ray and related technologies).
Normal VPN protocols (OpenVPN, Wireguard etc.) won't work by themselves as they're detected by My ISP and blocked.

But now I can't access some services because my connection gets flagged as suspicious by the online service providers such as Spotify and OpenAI (as a result of network Obfuscation and the IP being shared)

My connection works fine when tunneling a VPN (ex. Windscribe using wireguard) through another VPN (V2ray VPN/Proxy tunneling)

I have tested this by running a VPN on my computer and running the second VPN on a virtual machine running on my computer

**My question is how can I do the same thing without a VM?** either by running both apps in the same instance of windows or having another computer running a tunnel and sending the rest of the network's traffic through that computer?

**ps.** my modem/router is a TP-link TD-W8951ND incase you want to see what networking tools it supports

Comment: Did you find a solution? Also if you have another computer available, you can run VM guest as OS on that machine

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a similar setup without using a virtual machine (VM), you can use a technique called "tunneling through SSH." Here's a step-by-step guide to help you set it up:

1. Choose a computer within your network (either another Windows machine or a Linux machine) that can act as a tunneling server. For the sake of this guide, let's refer to it as "Server B."
2. On Server B, install an SSH server if it is not already installed. For Windows, you can use software like OpenSSH for Windows or Bitvise SSH Server. For Linux, OpenSSH is typically available by default.
3. Forward the necessary port for your V2Ray proxy on Server B. This will allow your local machine to connect to the V2Ray proxy running on Server B. The specific steps depend on the SSH server software you are using, so consult their documentation or tutorials for port forwarding.
4. On your local machine (your main Windows instance), install an SSH client software. For Windows, you can use software like PuTTY or OpenSSH for Windows. For Linux, OpenSSH is typically available by default.
5. Using the SSH client software on your local machine, initiate an SSH connection to Server B. Make sure to enable port forwarding during this connection.
6. Configure your V2Ray client on your local machine to connect to the locally forwarded port that points to Server B. This will effectively tunnel your V2Ray traffic through the SSH connection to Server B.
7. Configure the second VPN, such as Windscribe, on your local machine to use Server B as its endpoint. This will allow you to tunnel your entire network's traffic through Server B.

By following these steps, you should be able to achieve a similar setup as running the VM. However, instead of using a VM, you'll be using SSH tunneling to route the traffic through Server B. Remember to consult the documentation of the SSH server and client software you choose for more specific instructions related to port forwarding and connecting via SSH.

Comment: Intention is to not use another computer (or VM) Your solution is requiring another PC again.